# What is the purpose of the star resource path?

Tags: resources, aem, sling

Adobe AEM parsys component renders all children resources and if the WCM mode is set to the appropriate value, it displays *Drop component* section, which can be used to add new paragraphs. Implementation of the *Drop component* section is quite strange - it's embedded as a separate component with `<cq:include>`  tag, but the *path* parameter is set to `*` (star):

```
<cq:include path="*" resourceType="<%= newType %>"/>
```

(`newType` is a Java variable set before this line).

What happens here? What is the purpose of this star?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sling [provides a way](http://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/manipulating-content-the-slingpostservlet-servlets-post.html#algorithm-for-node-name-creation) to automatically create a resource name. If you send a POST request to an URL ending with a `/*`, Sling will generate the resource name, using a number of rules described in the documentation.

If you intercept the request sent to the `/*` resource in servlet or filter and invoke the `request.getResource()` method, you'll get a `StarResource` object. It extends the `SyntheticResource` type, representing resources that doesn't have appropriate node in the JCR. Its resource type is `sling:syntheticStarResource`, you can call its `getParent()` method, but generally it isn't very useful. An attempt to adapting it to `ValueMap` will fail. Sling provides a [helper method](https://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling7/org/apache/sling/api/resource/ResourceUtil.html#isStarResource-org.apache.sling.api.resource.Resource-) that checks if the given `Resource` is a `StarResource`.

In case of the paragraph system implementation mentioned in the question, the author of the code probably wanted to display the *Drop component* using a synthetic resource and providing `*` as the path is the easiest way to do it. You can also be sure that the resource will always be synthetic, as it's impossible to create a node with this name.